# How to run only specific command as root and other commands with default user in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

This is my Dockerfile.

```
FROM python:3.8.12-slim-bullseye as prod-env
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install unzip vim -y
COPY requirements.txt /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
USER nobody:nogroup
```

This is how **docker-compose.yml** looks like.

```
api_server:
    build:
      context: .
      target: prod-env
    image: company/server
    volumes:
      - ./shared/model_server/models:/models
      - ./static/images:/images
    ports:
      - 8200:8200
    command: gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8200 --threads "8" --log-level info --reload "server:gunicorn_app(command='start', project='app_server')"
```

I want to add permissions read, write and execute permissions on shared directories.

And also need to run couple of other coommands as root.

So I have to execute this command with root every time after image is built.

```
docker exec -it -u root api_server_1 bash -c "python copy_stuffs.py; chmod -R a+rwx models; chmod -R a+rwx /images"
```

Now, I want **docker-compose** to execute these lines.

But as you can see, user in docker-compose **has** to be `nobody` as specified by **Dockerfile**. So how can I execute root commands in docker-compose file?

Option that I've been thinking:
Install **sudo** command from Dockerfile and use **sudo**

Is there any better way ?

Comment: Could you clarify what is your usercase. Why this script has to be run after image is build? Most of the time scripts need to be executed when container starts or each time newer version of image is being used for service.

Comment: Yes, it needs to be executed when container starts or newer version of image is available. Is it better off to run these commands as standalone ? @DevilaN

Comment: Docker maintains the rights of the host, so give the folders on HostOS the rights with the user used in container. Due to the sandbox-approach of docker, containers should not be able to acquire stuff the host does not want to give (imho).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `docker-compose.yml` create another service using same image and volumes.

Override user with `user: root:root`, `command: your_command_to_run_as_root`,  for this new service and add dependency to run this new service before starting regular working container.

```
api_server:
    build:
      context: .
      target: prod-env
    image: company/server
    volumes:
      - ./shared/model_server/models:/models
      - ./static/images:/images
    ports:
      - 8200:8200
    command: gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:8200 --threads "8" --log-level info --reload "server:gunicorn_app(command='start', project='app_server')"
    # This make sure that startup order is correct and api_server_decorator service is starting first
    depends_on:
      - api_server_decorator
api_server_decorator:
    build:
      context: .
      target: prod-env
    image: company/server
    volumes:
      - ./shared/model_server/models:/models
      - ./static/images:/images
    # No ports needed - it is only decorator
    # Overriding USER with root:root
    user: "root:root"
    # Overriding command
    command: python copy_stuffs.py; chmod -R a+rwx models; chmod -R a+rwx /images
```

There are other possibilities like changing Dockerfile by removing USER restriction and then you can use entrypoint script doing as root what you want as privileged user and running `su - nobody` or better `exec gosu` to retain PID=1 and proper signal handling.

Comment: Won't this method cause `python copy_stuffs.py` to happen everytime I run `docker-compose up api_server` ? I won't want to copy stuffs again everytime as they are big files. `api_server_preannotation` should only run once, i.e when container is freshly built.

Comment: Then you have to run it by hand or add file with version tag in volume to check if this copy_stuff.py thing should be executed. There is no way current container will know from thin air which image version previous container had.

Comment: I have heard it is quite dangerous to use "root" on docker-compose files. Won't this method compromise security?

Comment: Also, if you look closely, /models and /images are mounted volumes, I don't suppose you can `chmod` mounted volumes from docker-compose.

Comment: @SauravPathak: why not? Mounted volumes are just bind-mount directories. There might be some issues with file owners and permissions when running docker on windows machine, but you haven't specified any details about your problem yet and this is so broad topic that I cannot guess what's going wrong on your machine without further info.

Answer (score 0):

In my eyes the approach giving a container root rights is quite hacky and dangerous.
If you want to e.g. remove the files written by container you need root rights on host as well.
If you want to allow a container to access files on host filesystem just run the container with appropriate user.

```
api_server:
   user: my_docker_user:my_docker_group
```

then give on host the rights to that group

```
sudo chown -R my_docker_user:my_docker_group models
```

Answer (score 0):

You should build all of the content you need into the image itself, especially if you have this use case of occasionally needing to run a process to update it (you are not trying to use an isolation tool like Docker to simulate a local development environment).  In your Dockerfile, `COPY` these directories into the image

```sh
COPY shared/model_server/models /models
COPY static/images /images
```

Do *not* make these directories writeable, and do not make the individual files in the directories executable.  The directories will generally be mode 0755 and the files mode 0644, owned by root, and that's fine.

In the Compose setup, do not mount host content over these directories either.  You should just have:

```yaml
services:
  api_server:
    build: .  # use the same image in all environments
    image: company/server
    ports:
      - 8200:8200
    # no volumes:, do not override the image's command:
```

Now when you want to update the files, you can rebuild the image (without interrupting the running application, without `docker exec`, and without an alternate user)

```sh
docker-compose build api_server
```

and then do a relatively quick restart, running a new container on the updated image

```sh
docker-compose up -d
```